# Best Way to check if a java.util.Date is older than 30 days compared to current moment in time?

Tags: java, date, compare

Here's what I want to do:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date eventStartDate = event.getStartDate();
```

How to check if eventStartDate is more than 30 days older than currentDate?

I'm using Java 8, Calendar isn't preferred.

Time zone is ZoneId.systemDefault().

Comment: What part of the current day? Which time zone? What is "one month" before March 30th or after January 30th? (It's not clear whether what you mean by "one month from current day".) Are you using Java 8, and can you use Joda Time if not? (This can be done with java.util.Calendar, but I'd avoid that if possible.)

Comment: Current day as in new Date(). 30 days. I do use Java8. I don't want to use Calendar.

Comment: "Current day as in new Date()" - that doesn't specify a day. It specifies a point in time. A point in time which is on March 25th here in London may be March 24th in San Francisco, for example. So we need to know which time zone to use. And "30 days" isn't the same as a month... if you really *mean* 30 days, please edit your question to say so.

Comment: Take a look at [Calendar API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). There is `add` method there and you can specify negative value if you want move date backward.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I rephrased the question and description. Time zone isn't an issue in this particular case.

Comment: @Abhi, it says older. If a date is older than another date, it means the older date repesents a moment in time which happened before the other date.

Comment: @SteveWaters: It certainly *is* an issue, unless you want to treat "30 days" as "30 * 24 hours", ignoring DST. Something which occurs at 1:30am local time may be exactly 30 * 24 hours before something which occurs as 2:30am local time, for example. With more context, we could help you a lot more...

Comment: @JonSkeet The only request is that "check if a certain service has started more than 30 days before current date." The service has a defined default Time Zone. Which is Helsinki.

Comment: @SteveWaters: Right, so you quite possibly want to use Helsinki as the time zone for the calculation. Or you should clarify the requirement with whoever requested it. Say "it's not an issue" just suggests it hasn't been considered. (The fact that it's expressed as "the current date" is somewhat alarming to start with... are we to assume it's really "the current point in time"?)

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree with your notions about vagueness. I checked and the default time zone used is ZoneId.systemDefault(). I added it to the description of my question.

Comment: @SteveWaters FYI, depending on the JVM’s default time zone is generally unwise. First, your code runs differently when moved across machines with any time zone designated in the host OS. Secondly, the JVM's current default time zone can be changed at *any* moment by *any* thread of *any* app running within that JVM; just takes a call to [`TimeZone.setDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-). Usually best to specify [the desired time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), such as `Europe/Helsinki`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Okay, assuming you really want it to be "30 days" in the default time zone, I would use something like:

```
// Implicitly uses system time zone and system clock
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime thirtyDaysAgo = now.plusDays(-30);

if (eventStartDate.toInstant().isBefore(thirtyDaysAgo.toInstant())) {
    ...
}
```

If "thirty days ago" was around a DST change, you need to check that the documentation for `plusDays` gives you the behaviour you want:

> When converting back to ZonedDateTime, if the local date-time is in an overlap, then the offset will be retained if possible, otherwise the earlier offset will be used. If in a gap, the local date-time will be adjusted forward by the length of the gap.

Alternatively you *could* subtract 30 "24 hour" days, which would certainly be simpler, but may give unexpected results in terms of DST changes.

Comment: Yes, well, 30 days for some reason is the requirement. Thank you, Mr. Skeet.

Answer (score 8):

You could try this:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date eventStartDate = event.getStartDate();
long day30 = 30l * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
boolean olderThan30 = currentDate.before(new Date((eventStartDate .getTime() + day30)));
```

It's disguisting, but it should do the job!

Comment: That's assuming every day is 24 hours long. That may or may not meet the requirements - they're unclear at the moment :(

Comment: I read your other comment too and I realized what do you mean by 24 hour long. You are right, it's not clear what does he mean by current date-30, but there are methods to truncate a date, so it's not impossible to solve this.

Comment: Remember to add "l" after first number ("30l") to let your compilator know that the operations are done on long numbers - otherwise you will exceed the range of Integer and the result will be totally wrong.

Comment: currentDate.after

Answer (score -1):

```
fun isOlderThan(interval: Int,previousTime : Long, currentTime: Long): Boolean {
    val currentDate = Date(currentTime)
    val previousDate = Date(previousTime)

    val diffCalculate = abs(currentDate.time - previousDate.time)
    val diffDays = diffCalculate / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

    return diffDays > interval
}
```

**Use**

```
val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd")
val oldDate = dateFormat.parse("2022-02-01")

if(isOlderThan(7,oldDate.time,System.currentTimeMillis()){
  Log.d("OLD CHECK","Old date is 7 days old")
}else{
  Log.d("OLD CHECK","Old day is not 7 days old")
}
```

Comment: Not recommended. The question wisely said *Calendar isn't preferred.* We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) used in the accepted answer. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android look into [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Comment: Ole V.V thank you for answer i update it .